# Loop through a list of unknown length in SASS

Tags: sass, frontend

I want to style a list of posts – I have seen a lot of great examples of that being done when the list is predefined

(list values are 1,2,3 – loop through and do something)

My question is: if it's possible to pick up a list length through SASS?

Answer (score 0):

SASS doesn't add any functionality to CSS, it just makes some kinds of CSS simpler to write.  If you can write it in CSS, it's possible with SASS.  If not, it isn't.